# The original Erdős-Volkmann ring problem

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, geometric-measure-theory

The Erdős-Volkmann ring problem and its solution are famous, but the original problem is actually still open. I'll describe this and a related problem from geometric measure theory, I think both of these problems deserve attention from set theorists. I would also be curious to hear about related problems. I first describe the common form of the two problems.

We have a property $P$ of subsets of Euclidean space such that

1. $\mathrm{ZF}\!+\!\mathrm{DC}$ implies that no Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $P$.
2. The proof of (1) shows that $\mathrm{ZF}\!+\!\mathrm{AD}\!+\!\mathrm{DC}$ implies that no subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $P$.
3. $\mathrm{ZFC}\!+\mathrm{CH}$ implies that some subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $P$.

**Question:** Does $\mathrm{ZFC}$ imply that some subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has $P$?

A positive answer implies that sets with $P$ are choice pathologies in a precise sense. A negative answer would produce a model of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ in which arbitrary subsets of Euclidean space have some of the nice properties that Borel sets have under $\mathrm{ZFC}$ - and this seem like an interesting possibility. I think that a negative answer might also be connected to cardinal invariants of the continumn.

Both problems involve Hausdorff dimension. We let $\mathrm{dim }(X)$ be the Hausdorff dimension of $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Recall that $\mathrm{dim}(X)$ is defined for an arbitrary subset $X$, in particular $X$ does not need to be measurable or anything. (In fact Hausdorff dimension is defined for arbitrary metric spaces.)

**Marstrand-Matilla  Projection** Suppose $m \le n$. The Marstrand-Matilla (MM) projection theorem states that if $X$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathrm{dim}(X) \le m$ then $\mathrm{dim}(\pi(X)) = \mathrm{dim}(X)$ for almost all orthogonal projections $\pi : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, and if $\mathrm{dim}(X) > m$ then $\pi(X)$ has positive $m$-dimensional Hausdorff measure (hence $\mathrm{dim}(\pi(X)) = m$) for almost all orthogonal projections $\pi : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$.

Let $P$ be the property "The MM theorem fails for $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$". Then (1)-(3) above holds. (1) and (2) follow from the usual proofs of Marstrand projection, (3) is due to Davies. Davies showed that $\mathrm{ZFC}\!+\!\mathrm{CH}$ implies that there is a subset $D$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\mathrm{dim}(X) = 2$ and $\pi(X)$ is Lebesgue null for every orthogonal projection $\pi : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.

So it is natural to ask if $\mathrm{ZFC}$ implies existence of a set like $D$. Another formulation: Is MM projection for arbitrary sets consistent with $\mathrm{ZFC}$? Davies's construction is in the paper "Two counterexamples concerning Hausdorff dimensions of projections". It's an easy paper to read, the construction is a straightforward transfinite induction.

Another question: What axioms (in addition to $\mathrm{ZFC}$) does Davies's construction actually require? $\mathrm{CH}$ should be overkill.

**Erdős-Volkmann** Erdős-Volkmann showed that for every $0 < d < 1$ there is a Borel subgroup of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ of Hausdorff dimension $d$. They asked the question of whether there are subrings of intermediate dimension. This question was answered independently by Bourgain and Edgar-Miller who showed the following: If $R$ is a Borel subring of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathrm{dim}(R) > 0$ then $R = \mathbb{R}$. The Bourgain proof is very difficult, but the Edgar-Miller proof is a gem. It just uses elementary algebra, linear algebra, and Marstrand projection. So there is a close connection to Marstrand projection - we have
$$\mathrm{ZF}\!+\!\mathrm{DC} \models (\mathrm{MM\hspace{2pt} for\hspace{2pt} arbitrary \hspace{2pt} sets} \Longrightarrow \mathrm{EV\hspace{2pt}for\hspace{2pt} arbitrary \hspace{2pt}subrings})$$

Let $P$ be the property "$R$ is a subring of $\mathbb{R}$ of dimension and $0 < \mathrm{dim}(R) < 1$". (1) and (2) follows from the Edgar-Miller paper. (3) is also due to Davies, but his work was never published and is unfindable. Fortunately, there is a 2016 paper by Maudlin which shows that $\mathrm{ZFC}\!+\!\mathrm{CH}$ implies that for every $0 < d < 1$ there is a subfield $F$ of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathrm{dim}(F) = d$. The paper is called "Subfields of $\mathbb{R}$ with arbitrary Hausdorff dimension".

So it is natural to ask if it is consistent with $\mathrm{ZFC}$ that every subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ has Hausdorff dimension $0$ or $1$. I believe that this question is essentially the original Erdős-Volkmann problem. In the literature the Erdős-Volkmann problem is usually taken to be "Is there a Borel subring of intermediate dimension?". However, it appears that the original question was not specifically about Borel subrings. I was a little uncertain about this because the original papers are in German, but Maudlin agrees, and he should know. Of course the original papers don't say anything about axioms, but it is most natural to ask what follows from $\mathrm{ZFC}$. Certainly Erdős himself would have been interested in the general non-Borel case, and there has been at least some interest from geometric measure theorists in the general case.

A final comment: The full Bourgain-Edgar-Miller theorem down not generalize to arbitrary subrings. Lindsay and Utev constructed a proper subring of $\mathbb{R}$ with Hausdorff dimension $1$, you can find this [here](https://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/%7Elindsaym/papers/erdos02vi12preprint.pdf). But their construction does not yield subrings of intermediate dimension.